# How to change setRowCount of lazyloading of p:datatable dynamically

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a situation where the pagination should be dynamically. Meaning that it should change with each call of the load method.

I want set the setRowCount() method dynamically and give the pagination for the dataTable

```java
@Override
public List<ProjectMasterModel> load(int first,int pageSize,StringsortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, String> filters) {
    List<ProjectMasterModel> data=new ArrayList<ProjectMasterModel>();
    LazyDataModel<ProjectMasterModel> newdata = null;
    ProjectMilestoneDaoImpl milestoneDaoImpl=(ProjectMilestoneDaoImpl) ObjectFactory.getBean("projectMilestoneDao");
    SessionFactory sessionFactory=(SessionFactory) ObjectFactory.getBean("sessionFactory");
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();

    try{
        data.addAll(milestoneDaoImpl.populateLazyRandomProjects(first,pageSize));
        setRowCount(milestoneDaoImpl.getRowCount_Of_ProjectList());

        // very important line to show the pagination

    }catch(Exception e){
        CmsLogger.errorLog(LazyProjectDataModel.class, e);
    }finally{   
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().close();
    }

    if(sortField != null)
       Collections.sort(data,new ProjectMasterModel());

    return data;
}
```

Here I have used a query to fetch the data size to set the row count.
In a given situation their may be number of records added to the Database.
So The pagination should increment dynamically.
But if I change the setRowCount() method to a dynamic value it doesn't reflect it keeps its original value which was set for the first time.

Answer (score 2):

PrimeFaces did not support this out of the box. [A fix has been checked in to trunk on Feb 11th 2016, tagged 6.0](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/51) (so it should at least be in the current 6.0RCx releases). I'm not sure if it is in the Elite release >=5.2.20 or >=5.3.7 (from Feb 12th)

One important reason for this not working is that the updated rowCount you might do in the load method serverside is **not** applied to the paginator client side. However, since it **is transferred from the server to the client**, you can update it in the oncomplete of each ajax call (page, sort, filter). In fact, that is a large part of the [patch](https://github.com/kukel/primefaces/commit/89beb68c6d3872d5187e071b95b247f45d18104b) (the other part is reading the value from the ajax response).

Combined calling this in e.g. the oncomplete of a ajax page event will solve the issue:

```
function updatePaginator(xhr, status, args) {
    var paginator = PF('DataTableWidgetVar').paginator;
    paginator.cfg.rowCount=args.totalRecords;
    paginator.cfg.pageCount = Math.ceil(value / paginator.cfg/rows)||1;
    paginator.updateUI();
}
```

You can then in each call in the load method,

- Try to read pageSize+1 records
- Set the count to this (pageSize+1) if you can read pageSize+1 (but still return pageSize records)
- Set the count to the number of rows read if they are pageSize or less.

Answer (score 2):

**MyMB.java**

```
List<NameClass> listResult = new LazyDataModel<NameClass>() {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Override
  public List<NameClass> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters) {

    List<NameClass> result = dao.findReg(....., pageSize, page);
    setRowCount(numberOfResult);
    return result;
  }
};

getListResult() {..}
setListResult(List<NameClass> l ) {...}
```

**myPage.xhtml**

```
<p:dataTable lazy="true" 
 value="#{myMB.listResult}" 
 var="model" 
 paginator="true"
 rows="#{myMB.pageSize}" 
 paginatorPosition="bottom" 
 paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}" >
```